# Cant switch voice when headset is connected to Agora

Tags: agora.io, android-audiomanager

Briefly, I use Agora Sdk's Voice call, the users change their roles, one is broadcaster and others Audience... When the user is broadcaster and his device is connected to headset, the other users (Audiences) cant hear him, but if I turned off headset, everything is okay, Can anyone help me how to switch audio routing to Headset?? I tried  override fun onAudioRouteChanged(routing: Int) Agoras method when routing is Headset, and I tried to user setEnableSpeakerphone(false)

Comment: With live streaming the default audio route is speakerphone. So, while using an external audio playback device such as a Bluetooth or wired headset `setEnableSpeakerphone(false)`, does not take effect. If the user already had the headset connected it will play audio through the same external device. 

You can try debugging the issue by using `onLocalAudioStateChanged` callback: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine_event_handler.html#a59946a989f87c737899e2284539adf09

Comment: Thank you, I have already fixed, the problem was in Headset's microphone, Clients and Me had the microphone with same problem :D, so I didnt imagine the problem in headset

Comment: Good to hear! All the best with your project.